# Managing the bibliography in LATEX

Tags: bibliographies

IS there any way that one can manage the way the bibliography appears; from journal to journal the citation modes are different. I would like to manage my .bbl or .bib file so in one journal the references appear as:

**Author year \em{Journal name} Volume Page**

and in another one appear as:

**Author \em{Journal name} \textbf{Volume} Page year**

***I do not want to do this manually for all the reference items***

Comment: That's exactly how it works with BibTeX ... The contents of the `.bib` file does not decide how the reference list appear, that is down to the bibliography style.

Comment: Welcome to TeX-sx! This is the basic idea behind BibTeX, which I assume you've come across as you've mentioned a `.bib` file.

Comment: Can you say how? I desperately need it!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format. I think that if you need it **desperately**, the best way to go is to do it manually now (since that will certainly work), and learn BibTeX or biblatex later.

Comment: Thanks! with 100 references I prefer to learn BibTex. It is more safe and avoids confusions.

Comment: Start by having a look into the biblatex documentation: http://ctan.sciserv.eu/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/biblatex.pdf

Comment: Is there a particular style you need (or want) to follow?  That may influence your decision between traditional BibTeX and `biblatex`. (Your description is far to vague to make a recommendation at this point.)

Comment: Is there any news here?